# Give a direct $\epsilon$-$N$ verification of the convergence of $\left\{\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{n}+3\right\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

> Using only the Archimedean Property of $\mathbb{R}$, give a direct $\epsilon$-$N$ verification of the convergence of $$\left\{\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{n}+3\right\}$$

---

Let $a_n=\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{n}+3$.

Since $a_n$ is converged to $3$, then $$\left\vert\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{n}+3-3\right\vert = \left\vert\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{n}\right\vert=\left\vert\frac{2\sqrt{n}+1}{n}\right\vert<\frac{2n+1}{n}<\frac{3}{\sqrt{n}}<\epsilon$$ then by the Archimedean Property, since $\epsilon/3>0$, then pick an index $N$ such that $1/\sqrt{N}<\epsilon/3$; thus for every $n\geq N$,

$$\left\vert\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{n}+3-3\right\vert <\frac{2n+1}{n}<\frac{3}{\sqrt{n}}<\frac{3}{\sqrt{N}}<\epsilon$$

---

I an not sure this is right because the question is asking a direct verification. Can anyone check the solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to solve for $N$: $\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{N}} < \epsilon\Rightarrow N > \dfrac{9}{\epsilon^2}$

Answer (score 1):

$\left\vert\frac{2}{\sqrt{N}}+\frac{1}{N}+3-3\right\vert = \left\vert\frac{2}{\sqrt{N}}+\frac{1}{N}\right\vert\leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{N}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\leq \frac{3}{\sqrt{N}}\leq\epsilon$ thus $N\geq[\frac{9}{\epsilon^2}]+1$

Comment: Why need to add 1

Comment: because may []=0 but we need $N\in \mathbb{N}$